# Update PostegreSQL with previous row value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to update my base SellAll with the value of a the previous row stock.
May be there is something that i dont understand because the result seems good at the moment of the update but i want the good stock of the previous row after the update and it seems not the case.

I have this request so far :

```
UPDATE SellAll set stock =  monthn1.stock
FROM  
(
    SELECT  (in - out)+LAG(stock,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY famille,year, month) AS stock, id
    FROM SellAll
) AS monthn1
WHERE SellAll.id = monthn1.id and monthn1.stock<>0;
```

But i don t have the result wanted.
For example i have this grid
[image]

With my request i have this
[image]

But i want this :
[image]

I want to subtract (in - out) + stock of previous row
Can you help me ?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: "With my request i have this"  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/AfKfnGUA )

Comment: The red 7 (in third row) is the old value for the 2nd row (`2`) + `84-79` = 7.  you want/need the new value (`-7`) and add `84-79` to it.  (My answer is (also) not doing that, so I will delete it for now...)

Comment: BTW: I have the old values from your previous edit, but in general you should read: [Please do not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) , while I am still thinking on how to solve this., using the _old_ values.......)